# Using Realm Mobile Platform with watchKit

Tags: ios, realm, watchkit, watch, realm-mobile-platform

I am trying to use the new feature of Realm, Mobile Platform.

Everything is good when I implement it on the iOS side like in the demo code.
I can communicate with the macOS app from it.

So I tried to implement it on the watch but whenever I try to launch it on the watch simulator, it crashes and the error says:

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::runtime_error: Encryption not enabled
```

I am using the localhost server address.

Do you know how I can fix that and launch it on the watch?

Comment: This sounds like a bug rather than something you're doing wrong. Please file a bug report against Realm at https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/new.